Sort by Adding Cells Until the Sum Reaches 60
I have an example data set. The numbers represent minutes.
lunch       48.00
study       90.00
nap         45.00
workout     30.00
dinner      20.00
meal prep   60.00
pray        21.00

I would like to sort this data so that I can know how much of each activity will be done with a specific hour of the day (i.e. workout and dinner can be done within the same hour, but lunch and study will need to be spread out of multiple hours). I would like to keep the existing order of activities.
My goal is to get as many sums of 60 from this data set as possible.
Below I have listed the desired results.
Hour 1 ( 48 mins lunch & 12 mins study)  60 min total
Hour 2 ( 60 mins study) 60 min total
Hour 3 ( 18 mins in study & 42 mins nap) 60 min total
Hour 4 ( 3 mins nap & 30 mins workout & 20 mins dinner & 7 mins meal prep) 60 min total
Hour 5 ( 53 min meal prep & 7 mins pray) 60 min total
Hour 6 (4 min pray)

This feels like a homework problem. Is this an assignment given by a teacher or tutor of some sort?

I need to be taking whatever class that might be.
It is not an assignment. I am trying to add some automation to a process at my job. The data is just an example I made up with random easy numbers.

What does this question have to do with sorting?

@Scott-СлаваУкраїні I am thinking of it as sorting the amount of time dedicated to tasks into specific hours of the day.
Is there a better way to describe what I am asking for?

If one has Office 365:
=LET(
    _it,A1:A15,
    _MN,B1:B15,
    _sum,SUM(_MN),
    _s,SEQUENCE(_sum),
    _hr,SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(_sum/60,0)),
    _arr,HSTACK(_s,INDEX(_it,MATCH(_s,VSTACK(0,SCAN(1,_MN,LAMBDA(_z,_y,_z+_y)))))),
    _rd,REDUCE(0,_hr,LAMBDA(_a,_b,VSTACK(_a,UNIQUE(FILTER(HSTACK(SEQUENCE(_s,,_b,0),TAKE(_arr,,-1)),(TAKE(_arr,,1)>=60*(_b-1)+1)*(TAKE(_arr,,1)<=60*_b)))))),
    _drp,DROP(_rd,1),
    _rw,BYROW(_drp,LAMBDA(_t,COUNTA(FILTER(TAKE(_arr,,-1),(TAKE(_arr,,1)>=60*(@INDEX(_t,1,1)-1)+1)*(TAKE(_arr,,1)<=60*@INDEX(_t,1,1))*(TAKE(_arr,,-1) = @INDEX(_t,1,2)))))),
    VSTACK(HSTACK("Hour","Item","Minutes"),HSTACK(_drp,_rw)))

This will take the inputs and first create an array of every minute and the activity happening in that minute.  Then it uses Filter to first filter by each hour.  Then it uses that to do another filter to count the number of minutes of each activity in that hour.  Then it stacks it all together with the titles to spill the results.


Much appreciated Scott!

Proposal for a solution with formulas as shown in the following illustration:

Cell contents:
D2: 1
E2: =INDEX($A$1:$A$15,1)
F2: =IF(E2="","",MIN(VLOOKUP(E2,$A$1:$B$15,2,FALSE)-SUMIF(E$1:E1,E2,F$1:F1), 60-SUMIF(D$1:D1,D2,F$1:F1)))
D3: =IF(SUM(F$2:F2)=SUM($B$1:$B$15), "", IF(SUMIF(D$2:D2,D2,F$2:F2)<60,D2,D2+1))
E3: =IF(D3="","",IF(SUMIF(E$2:E2,E2,F$2:F2)<VLOOKUP(E2,$A$1:$B$15,2,FALSE), E2, INDEX($A$1:$A$15,MATCH(E2,$A$1:$A$15,0)+1)))
